# How do I turn logging off for Elasticsearch in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, logging

I'm using the `elasticsearch` npm module. I get annoying yellow warnings because my elasticsearch server is currently off.

How can I make it so that it doesn't log anything?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  log : [{
    type: 'stdio',
    levels: ['error', 'warning'] // change these options
  }]
});
```

So if you just wanted errors showing up it would be.

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  log : [{
    type: 'stdio',
    levels: ['error'] // change these options
  }]
});
```

More can be found on [config](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/client-configuration.html) page. Different logging levels are found [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/logging.html) (old link dead).

**UPDATE: ES 7.x - logging has been removed:**
[Breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/breaking-changes.html), [Observability](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/observability.html)

Comment: change those options to what?

Comment: Add little more information and another link to the different logging levels available.

Comment: links are broken

Answer (score 0):

I came to this thread because I was getting verbose logs for every elasticsearch query in the nodejs app I'm working on.

Turned out to be a package called `elasticsearch-query-builder`. It looks for an environment variable named `VERBOSE_LOG`, which I had to unset (i.e. to not set to `false`, which is a truthy string value)